# YARA: Match string without a specific substring

Tags: yara

I'm trying to create a YARA rule which matches a URL plus one arbitrary directory, while excluding a specific directory. For example, it needs to match any of these:

```
https://example.com/foo
https://example.com/bar
https://example.com/eggs
https://example.com/eggsAndHam
https://example.com/greenEggs
https://example.com/anythingatall
```

But specifically not this:

```
https://example.com/baz
```

To complicate things, the file must match if it contains a URL with an arbitrary directory in addition to the exuded URL. So a file that contained the following would match:

```
https://example.com/ougsrhoiujrnae
https://example.com/baz
```

As would the following:

```
https://example.com/biuhOIUYui
```

But not the following by itself:

```
https://example.com/baz
```

This would be trivial if YARA supported negative lookaheads like `https:\/\/example\.com\/(?!baz)`, but it does not. Is there a way to accomplish this in YARA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish this if you know the length of the first part of the string is:

1. select the strings with a regular expression
2. loop through the returned offsets
3. for each offset, add the length of the known part of the string
4. check if the offset + known string length is followed by the string we want to exclude, and exclude it if so

For the above example, we know that `https://example.com` is 19 bytes long, and we can exclude the match if it is followed by the string `/bar`:

```
rule url_not_ending_in_bar
{
    strings:
        $url = /https:\/\/example\.com\/\w*/
        $exclude = "/bar"

    condition:
        for any i in (1..#url): (
            not $exclude at @url[i] + 19
        )
}
```